# Unhandled Promise Rejection in Angular 2

Tags: angularjs, angular

Few minutes ago, i just run into a 404 error in my angular 2 app. There are no errors in my terminal although there are some 404 errors in my console. I have included bootstrap in my node_modules in the angular-cli.json file. However, i dont't know where the unhandled promise rejection is coming from. Any idea on how to resolve this issue?

[image]

```
**404 error**

        Unhandled Promise rejection: Failed to load ../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Failed to load ../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css undefined

        ZoneAwareError {__zone_symbol__error: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Failed to load ../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css
            at resolvePromis…, rejection: "Failed to load ../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css", promise: ZoneAwarePromise, zone: Zone, task: ZoneTask}

    GET http://localhost:4200/css/local.css 404 (Not Found)

**angular-cli**
{
  "project": {
    "version": "1.0.0-beta.28.3",
    "name": "frontend"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css",
         "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
         "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",




      ],
      "scripts": [





      ],
      "environments": {
        "source": "environments/environment.ts",
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "files": "src/**/*.ts",
      "project": "src/tsconfig.json"
    },
    {
      "files": "e2e/**/*.ts",
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.json"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "prefixInterfaces": false,
    "inline": {
      "style": false,
      "template": false
    },
    "spec": {
      "class": false,
      "component": true,
      "directive": true,
      "module": false,
      "pipe": true,
      "service": true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I guess you are using bootstrap and it cannot load that as the folder path is incorrect

Comment: now, i don't know of the bootstrap file path it is referencing to. Because i dont have any other bootstrap folder aside the one in the node_modules folder

Comment: are you using any Global css file or any local.css in your app?

Comment: Can you show your angular-cli.json file?

Comment: @JayChase, angular-cli.json updated

Comment: @RahulSingh, i am using a local.css

Comment: [The wiki page of angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-include-bootstrap) says: When you make changes to `.angular-cli.json` you will need to re-start `ng serve` to pick up configuration changes. So did you make sure you reloaded the project properly?

Comment: @VohidjonKarimjonov, i have reloaded the project over and over :)

Comment: your folder structure?? where is the local.css is present and where have you refereed in your app? and ur component code?

Comment: @Aravind, i have updated my question. I have the local.css file but i haven't referred it anywhere in my app. I deleted the path i referred to local.css in my component to see if the error would go but the error still persists, even same with the bootstrap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made mistake in your **app.dashboard.html** as below,

[image]

Which should be as

[image]